# I have start and end date - how to count

Tags: excel

I have start date and would like to count it like this...

```
StartDate   End Date
2/4/2015    7/22/2015
7/22/2015   
2/2/2015    8/1/2015
7/26/2015   
10/8/2014   10/21/2014
```

I would like to count membership so to show me for each month how many active members I had?

How would I do this in excel?

Comment: you mean you have start date. while some has end date too.. right?? then what you want from this?

Comment: so if my date is 2/4/2015    7/22/2015 and I would like to count that this memeber card was active in February (1),March (1),April (1),May(1),June(1),July(1) and this date is 2/2/2015    8/1/2015 then Feb(1),March (1),April (1),May(1),June(1),july(1),august(1)...so total is February (2),March(2),April(2)........August(1)

Comment: yes then what?? if your date is 2/4/2015 - 7/22/2015 then what man?? what you want?? i know ur start end date. but what you want from these two dates?

Comment: Please include the other data you want to use (how many members).  All we can tell you here is that you can "do math" with dates, to find the number of days inbetween. Simply just use `A2-A1` or wherever your cells are.  After that, you'll need to give us some more info. about how we/you'd know the active member count.

Comment: i would like to find how many active members i had in Feb,March,April and so on

Comment: I am trying to find how many active members i had in  each month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it.

use `=IF(1>=MONTH($A3),IF(1>MONTH(IF($B3<>"",$B3,NOW())),0,IF($D3<>0,1,0)),0) + $E3` to calculate the months in year range. its for Jan. you can modify for feb to dec.

And total all values to find the sum.  check the image.  If you want this. I will give u the link to download this spread sheet.

[image]

**UPDATE**

Download the excel file from here. 
[DownloadLink](http://mytactics.blogspot.ae/p/downloadingpage.html?DownloadId=0Bxxluya0NKB2al91bWxGMWZLOG8)

**UPDATE**
As if above excel you can not open properly give it a try.
download the excel formula that i applied on excel file. [Formula](https://mytactics.blogspot.com/p/downloadingpage.html?DownloadId=0Bxxluya0NKB2Uy1IWFFxbkRWaGM)

open new excel.

1. select the cell **A1**
2. tab "Data"
3. from ribbon select the option to import the data from text.
4. choose the text file download above. and say "Finish" then "Ok"
5. then you will get the excel file ready.

Let me know still you can not get excel file working. Make it sure you have "Date" Formatting applied on first 2 columns

Comment: Why when i open the file in each cell i get #NAME?

Comment: u have ms office right? specially ms excel? did you unblock the file? as u download from internet. so windows by default lock the file. select this excel > right click >  properties > general tab > at last "Unblock" button. hit it and unblock the file. then see if it helps. but I tested it and seems to be working to me.  check the image is this is what you wanted.

Comment: Yes thats whats i did and but file still shows #value.  Its close to what i wanted.  For example in first date it shows january 2.  But it should one entry for january 2015 and one entry for jam 2016.

Comment: I didnt consider year. consider months only. mean for 1-1-2015  to 1-1-2016 it will be 2 jan. 1 jan for 2015 and 1 jan for 2016.  and in which cell u r getting `#value` because i dont find such issue. its working fine in my both systems. which office u have?

Comment: copy the following value as it is and paste it in A3 - that will make a row ready for you. check update.

Comment: That worked but is there a way to do this via pivot table?

Comment: what do u mean by do this via pivot? what exactly you want to do and how?